# c# hiding confusion

Tags: c#

This is confusing to me please expalin me the behaviour of this?

A declaration of a new member hides an inherited member only within the scope of the new member.
Copy

```
**class Base
{
   public static void F() {}
}
class Derived: Base
{
   new private static void F() {}   // Hides Base.F in Derived only
}
class MoreDerived: Derived
{
   static void G() { F(); }         // Invokes Base.F
}**
```

**In the example above, the declaration of F in Derived hides the F that was inherited from Base, but since the new F in Derived has private access, its scope does not extend to MoreDerived. Thus, the call F() in MoreDerived.G is valid and will invoke Base.F.**

I am not understanding that how `static void G() { F(); }` can access the base class f method when it can access all methods of it's immediate super class and super class hides the f method of base class

Comment: It can't invoke `Derived::F()`, because that method is private.  Outside of `Derived`, `Derived::F()` may as well not exist at all.  You may need to change your example a bit, unless that makes everything work -- in which case, you have your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MoreDerived` cannot access *all* methods of its super class; in particular, it cannot access `private` methods. In C#, anything marked `private` in a class is invisible to anything outside of that class. In other words, adding or removing a `private` method will not change how anything outside of that class compiles. Since the `new private static void F` is invisible to the outside world, `MoreDerived` is unaffected by it.

If the modifier was `protected` instead, `MoreDerived` *would* see it.

In the example you gave, the `new` keyword only changes the meaning of names in the namespace. It does not change what methods are available. A method of `Derived` can still call `Base.F()` like so:

```
class Derived: Base 
{ 
   new private static void F()
   {
       F();      // calls Derived.F()
       Base.F(); // calls Base.F()
   }
} 

class MoreDerived: Derived 
{ 
   static void G() 
   {
       F();         // Invokes Base.F
       Derived.F(); // Invokes Base.F because Derived.F is private
       Base.F();    // Invokes Base.F
   }
}
```

It's analogous to this example:

```
class Foo
{
    int bar; // in most methods, this variable can be accessed as just "bar"

    Foo(int bar) // this parameter will hide the instance member bar
    {
        this.bar = bar; // instance method can still be accessed, though
    }
}
```

Comment: Faster on the gun, guess I don't have to finish my paragraph.  :)  +1

Comment: that's ok but how the morederived class can have access to the base class method when it is not available to it's immediate super class that is only my confusion

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet : See my answers for your above comment

Comment: NoviceToDotNet: If you see my edits, the `F` method of `Base` *is still accessible to `Derived`*, just not without qualification.

Comment: But here i am not using any qualification`static void G() { F(); }` so how is it possible to acces base class method very confusing sir please explain me

Comment: NoviceToDotNet: The `new private` designation just means that *within the context of `Derived`*, `F` has a new meaning. To everybody outside of `Derived`, `Derived.F` means the same as `Base.F`.

Comment: different meaning means if i am not wrong different behavior i think and when we want to provide different behavior to same method of base class then y we need to write a method in derived class with the NEW key word please explain me this

Comment: NoviceToDotNet: I'm having trouble figuring out what you're asking. Is there something in particular that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: just i am trying to understand a OOPs concept which is troubling me a lot tats what i am asking to u

Comment: one more thing if i remove private from the derived class method then in moreDerived class i will be having both method of derived class as well as base class

Comment: i mean to say that if in derived class i remove the private key word then in moreDerived class which method will it call base class method of derived class method. And as you told that in derived class both base class method will be also available then how the moreDerived class will resolve which method from the both should be call in derived class

Answer (score 1):

'new' keyword will hide the base member if it is allowded to be access outside the class.

But due to the inheritance chain MoreDerived : Derived : Base , you will see the public members of immeditae base or the higher base classes in the chain.

Method hiding is not equal to the private modifier on a method.

Comment: see hiding means that the base class method is hidden in the derived class bcas of NEW kwy word  in derived class. Now it is not acccessible to out side world. So how is this available to moreDerived class this is only my Question

Comment: Due to the inheritance chain MoreDerived:Derived:Base , so now if you hide base's F method in derived and make it private so in the more dervied class there is nothing public that it can see in its immediate parent (Derived) thus it ladder up the chain and see if any other class is having F() and in your case yes it is Base , so compiler makes it avaliable for you.

Comment: but a i am gain confuse with this that a derived class can see in it's immediate super class so how can moreDerived class can go to the base class please explain me sir

Comment: `MoreDerived` can access static methods from both `Base` and `Derived`. When it accesses `F`, it gets the one inherited from `Derived`, which is the `F` inherited from `Base` because `Derived.F` is private.

Comment: so n conclusion i shud say that in the derived class both the methods are available but the prviate key word limites the access of the derived class method but the base classmethod is inherited to moreDerived class m i correct? But i am uncler whih what is the need of shadowing with the NEW key word in derived class in general i want to know y we will shadowing in any case. And if i remove the private  from the derived class method then moreDerived will have access to both method of base class and derived class please explain me